# Plugin for eclipse for displaying 3D objects

Tags: eclipse-plugin, flexbuilder, javafx, 3d, java-3d

I have  a XML file based on UML, which contains information about the classes, methods, packages and I have to interpret it and display it into 3D format where in classes would be represented by rectangles and packages with some other geometric figure and so forth.Also I would be able to change its view but just moving my mouse in a particular direction.

I was looking in for a particular plugin for eclipse which can help me in doing that. I had in my list few options like Java FX, Java 3D, ardor 3D and flex plugin with eclipse. which would be the best and easy to use one from the above for catering to my requirements,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official Eclipse poroject for this kind of visualization is:

**[GEF3D](http://www.eclipse.org/gef3d/)**

> GEF3D is an Eclipse GEF extension bringing 3D to diagram editing. That is with GEF3D you can create 3D diagrams, 2D diagrams and combine 3D with 2D diagrams.
>   GEF3D extends GEF by providing 3D enabled draw and controller classes. Instead of drawing 2D figures, you can now draw 3D figures.

[image]

(Note: even though the above illustration is not exactly what you want, you still can use GEF3D to achieve what you want and design 3D rectangles)